# preg_match for string not work

Tags: php

i have string like `p88t9014-name` here is `p` is for Product and `t` for sub product id
and after `-` the `name` is user defined any name.
i try to match string with `preg_match` with this code ::

```
$name="p88t0056-name";
if(preg_match('/p[0-9]t[0-9]-[A-Z,a-z]/',$name,$match)) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "No";
}
print_r($m);
```

i just try to match formate if is this with format `p[number]t[number]-[anystring]`. but my code is not working.

Comment: Can the name contain a comma?

Comment: If not you should remove the comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put quantifiers after your character classes:

```
'/p[0-9]+t[0-9]+-[A-Za-z]+/'
```

Comment: Add parenthesis for your $match to have the parts in it: /p([0-9])+t([0-9])+-([A-Za-z])+/

Comment: And possibly `^` at beginning and `$` at the end, since it looks he is trying to match the whole string.

Answer (score 2):

This regex will work for you:

`/p(\d+)t(\d+)-(\w+)/g`

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xW0vS8)

**Explaination:**

`p` matches letter p

`\d+` matches numbers 0-9

`t` matches letter t

`\d+` matches numbers 0-9

`-` matches dash '-'

`\W+` match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
and g to catch all matches.

I am also not an expert on regex but trying multiple options on http://www.regex101.com helps as it shows explanations of characters in right side panel. Hope it helps in future :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're always going to have a set number of digits, you can also use:

```
 /^p[0-9]{2}t[0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z]+$/
```

Here's an example on RegExr: http://www.regexr.com/390ds

Answer (score 0):

in regex `[0-9]` matches exactly one character, and so does `[A-Z,a-z]`, and therefore $name is not match the pattern you give. Strings like "p8t0-A" and "p0t2," pass the test.

Besides, another problem in your pattern is that: `[A-Z,a-z]` matches not only alphabets but also `,` (a single comma). I guess the pattern you need is `p[0-9]+t[0-9]+-[A-Za-z]+`, in which `+`s represent "occurs at least once".